# Community Ad for Cartography in Area 51

Tags: discussion

I've proposed a new site, "[Cartography](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/101932/cartography?referrer=eB8KJkkaBh0tAmQDgW1TOg2)" in Area 51: Proposed Q&A site for those interested in maps and map-making, historical or contemporary, real or fictional.  I believe that others in the Game Development community might be interested in such a site for their work and to see other ideas, both fictional and real, with regards to creating maps for games and such.

I know advertising this in the non-meta is disallowed on SE sites, but I'm not sure how community ads work, or if it's something that enough people would think was a good thing to point the Game Development community toward.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know advertising this in the non-meta is disallowed on SE sites, but
>   I'm not sure how community ads work, or if it's something that enough
>   people would think was a good thing to point the Game Development
>   community toward.

You should make a [community promotion ad](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/community-promotion-ads-2016). To do this, post an "answer" to that linked post containing an image of the appropriate size. The answers to that ads thread should be pre-filled with a template so you basically just need to fill it out and supply the ad image.

This will be both bump the ad thread so people see it on the active page of meta, and then provide the community a way to vote on your ad. Once it gets a certain number of upvotes it will be displayed on the main site.

Comment: Ah, excellent.  Thank you.  I've been an SE user for years, but rarely have done anything meta, and the community ads and Area 51 are very new to me.  I'll put an image together.  Thanks!